# How to convert Scala List to Java ArrayList

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I am using a Java API that requires ArrayList as parameter. Now in Scala, I have a List[String]. How can I convert the List[String] to ArrayList in Scala?

I have tried :

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val scalaList = List("a","b","c")
scalaList.asJava
```

Result is:

```
java.util.List[String] = [a, b, c]
```

The above does not work because I want the result to be

> java.util.ArrayList[String]

instead of

> java.util.List[String] = [a, b, c]

Comment: `ArrayList<T>` is implementation of `List<T>` in Java. It makes sense to return `List<T>`.

Comment: List<T> is the interface type that represents any list, and as such it is what most people take as parameter instead of a specific instance. Taking the specific instance without specific comment, and in particular one like ArrayList, should always at least be documented with a good reason.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It totally makes sense to return `java.util.List[T]` which is a java interface and can have `ArrayList[T]` or `LinkedList[T]` as implementation.

```
scala> val scalaList = List(1,2,3) 
scalaList: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> import scala.collection.JavaConverters._  
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

scala> scalaList.asJava
res22: java.util.List[Int] = [1, 2, 3]
```

**In my opinion it needs to be converted to `ArrayList[T]` or `LinkedList[T]` whatever you want by yourself.**

One way I could think of is

```
scala> new java.util.ArrayList[Int](scalaList.asJava)
res27: java.util.ArrayList[Int] = [1, 2, 3]
```

or

```
scala> new java.util.LinkedList[Int](scalaList.asJava)
res28: java.util.LinkedList[Int] = [1, 2, 3]
```

**Better version of this would be**

```
scala> def toArrayList[T](input: List[T]): java.util.ArrayList[T] = new java.util.ArrayList[T](input.asJava)
toArrayList: [T](input: List[T])java.util.ArrayList[T]

scala> toArrayList(List(1000, 2000, 3000))
res33: java.util.ArrayList[Int] = [1000, 2000, 3000]
```

**And the best version would be, write implicit method**

```
class AsArrayList[T](input: List[T]) {
  def asArrayList : java.util.ArrayList[T] = new java.util.ArrayList[T](input.asJava)
}

implicit def asArrayList[T](input: List[T]) = new AsArrayList[T](input)

List(1000, 2000, 3000).asArrayList
```

Comment: i tried, val input = List("a","b","c"); myapi(new java.util.ArrayList [String](input.asJava)); But got "value asjava is not a member of List[String]".

Comment: did you import `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._`, thats where `asJava` method is

Comment: `scala.collection.JavaConverters` has been deprecated since Scala 2.13.0. You should import the extension methods with `import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._`.